# Border around Google Doc (word processing)

Tags: google-docs

I'd like to add a simple, black, one-pixel border around a Google Doc (regular word processing doc) for a flier I'm writing. What is the easiest way to do this? And are there options for adding other kinds of borders? I didn't find anything great in the Docs user-submitted template collection, and I hear that it's closing down soon anyway.

Answer (score 4):

To add a border around your Google Doc use the "Insert Table" with the 1x1 option. Put your content inside and change the format of the table line as you wish.

[image]

If you want the borders to be closer to the margin go to `File -> Page Setup...` and edit the margins.